# Javascript nested array to object conversion

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects in the following format. It basically a nested array of objects. I tried to do it using a recursive function, but I failed to organize the nested object.

```
[
  {
    "id": "31a3sd2f1a3ds21f",
    "name": "Energy device",
    "child": [
      {
        "id": "65sa4d65a4sdf654adsf",
        "name": "Device 2",
        "child": [
          {
            "id": "65a4d65ad4s54adsf",
            "name": "Device 3",
            "child": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "6as54d54as5f",
    "name": "Energy device 2",
    "child": [
      {
        "id": "9a8s7df98a78sdf",
        "name": "Device 4",
        "child": [
          {
            "id": "65a4d65ad4s54adsf",
            "name": "Device 5",
            "child": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "65asd54as5f4",
        "name": "Device 5-1",
        "child": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to convert it to the following format.

```
{
  "31a3sd2f1a3ds21f": {
    "65sa4d65a4sdf654adsf": {
      "65a4d65ad4s54adsf": ""
    }
  },
  "6as54d54as5f": {
    "9a8s7df98a78sdf": {
      "65a4d65ad4s54adsf": ""
    },
    "65asd54as5f4": ""
  }
}
```

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Hi Nasir, can you please post your code/attempt with your recursive function and highlight what specifically you're having issues with?

Comment: you didn't explain in detail how you expect children to be transformed. You always have max one child for all the nodes in your tree despite it being an array. The resulting output in your example just transforms children as properties of the parent object. Is that interpretation correct? Actually you expained it through the example but I wanted to be sure I got it right

Comment: Here you see the value of "id" is the key of the expected object's key. If an object of the array has a child, then the object's value will be another object from its child. Otherwise an empty string. Suppose my array is `[{"id":1, "child":[{"id":2, "child":[]}, {"id":3, "child":[{"id": "4", "child":[]}]}}]` Then my expected output will be like this `{"1":{"2":"", "3": { "4": ""}}}`

Comment: yes I was just highlighting the fact that you use an array for the property child when it wouldn't be needed if it was one child only. It could be called children and it would already support the option to have multiple objects in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map each object within your array to new arrays of the shape `[key, value]`. For each object, you can extract the id and child properties using desturcutring assignment in your callback argument `({id, child}) => ...)`. You can then return an array for that object that represents an entry for the new object your building. The key is the `id` of the current object, and the value is either a new object based on the `child` array which you can build by doing a recursive call, or an empty string if your current object doesn't have any children. This allows you to add the nesting to the objects as you build them. Finally, you can wrap the mapped version of your `arr` into a call to `Object.fromEntries()` which allows you to convert the array of `[key, value]` pair entries into an object:

```js
const arr = [ { "id": "31a3sd2f1a3ds21f", "name": "Energy device", "child": [ { "id": "65sa4d65a4sdf654adsf", "name": "Device 2", "child": [ { "id": "65a4d65ad4s54adsf", "name": "Device 3", "child": [] } ] } ] }, { "id": "6as54d54as5f", "name": "Energy device 2", "child": [ { "id": "9a8s7df98a78sdf", "name": "Device 4", "child": [ { "id": "65a4d65ad4s54adsf", "name": "Device 5", "child": [] } ] }, { "id": "65asd54as5f4", "name": "Device 5-1", "child": [] } ] } ];

const mapToId = (arr) => Object.fromEntries(arr.map(({id, child}) => [
  id, child.length ? mapToId(child) : ""
]));

const res = mapToId(arr);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @NasirKhan No worries - in the future, please remember to add your code and attempt. It helps us see what you're struggling with and it shows that you've put in effort in solving your issue yourself first

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you wanted the final child to be an empty string instead of an empty object, but here it is:

```
function arrayToObject(array) {
    // Create empty object if array has cildren, else create an empty string
    const obj = array.length > 0 ? {} : '';

    // Recursively add children to object
    array.forEach((item) => {
        obj[item.id] = arrayToObject(item.child);
    });

    return obj;
}
```